# Duplicate accounts in accounts tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, linked-accounts

For [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381077/satyrwilder?tab=accounts), his accounts tab shows three entries for "Database Administrators". It's the same account listed three times:

[image: account listing]

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2753596/maksim-luzik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Joe Friend (and a few others) have two Stack Overflow accounts, each tied to the same Stack Exchange profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310019/why-does-joe-friend-and-a-few-others-have-two-stack-overflow-accounts-each-ti)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this profile got fixed up at some point along the way.

I did, however, clean up the dupe profile for the user mentioned in the comments. (The cause there was a duplicate row in a shared table we use to keep track of basic information about people's profiles for ease of access network-wide.)