# Duplicate accounts in community list

Tags: bug, profile-page, communities-list

[This <s>troll</s> user who doesn't behave according to the Code of Conduct / Terms of Service](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/203378/goodd-hueman) has a rather interesting community list; it seems he joined Mathematics *twice*. One of the links ends up at a [suspended account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/582297/), the [other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/582294/) doesn't exist (maybe because it was deleted as no longer welcome).

[image]

I can't check whether the account is duplicated on the accounts tab as in [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111107/duplicate-accounts-in-accounts-tab) because the [link to their network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/14107440/goodd-hueman) is broken (which reminds me of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313699/295232)).

Comment: I noticed that too. I think two accounts got merged.

Comment: @Xufox more likely that they got suspended, deleted the account and re-created it hoping to dodge the suspension. <The suspension period ends on Aug 21 at 9:46 - joined Aug 7 at 9:47> (credit to Mithrandir for the idea)

Comment: How long has Stack Exchange been hiding a Panda? Just tried to check out the [Network Profile](//stackexchange.com/users/14107440) of the user and ended up at a page with a sign pointing to a Panda. I wanna see the Panda. Where is the Panda? I *luv* Pandas ;-)

Comment: @DonaldDuck I doubt it (but as mentioned in the question, I can't check their network profile to make sure) – it's more likely to be caused by the account being deleted and recreated.